# I can not connect to SMB shares from macOS Mojave

Tags: macos, mojave, smb

I have NAS. I can successfully connect to it from Dune player, Xiaomi player, windows 7 PC, windows 7 pc inside virtual machine on my macbook.

But I can't connect from my macbook and from my imac anymore.

I can see NAS in network, but if click on it it say "unable to connect".

How to fix it?

Comment: What kind/brand of NAS? Which SMB version is supported on the NAS? What does "can't connect … anymore" mean? Did it work before? Have you changed anything on the macOS side or on the NAS side?

Comment: Hi Gummibando. It is Thecus. I have fixed the issue this way: have added user/pass. With guest it is not accessible anymore.